# ADF - Edit multiple rows of detail table simultaneously from master table

Tags: java, oracle-adf, master-detail

My query surrounds the Master-Detail relationship in Oracle ADF Development.

What i am trying to do is make a "batch" change to all rows of a particular detail table without having to change each row individually.

For example, i have a master table of countries and corresponding detail tables of all the cities within those countries. The cities table has a column for "dialing code". If i select "UK" from the countries table i want to be able to populate the "dialing code" column of all the cities in UK with the value "+44" without having to go through them one by one.

Is this possible? I'm assuming a Master-Detail relationship is perfect for this but if not, what else is out there?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a service method on your master VO that iterates through all the details of a row and updates an attribute in them.
You can then expose that service method to the client and drag it to add it to a page you are building.
Some links:
http://download.oracle.com/otn_hosted_doc/jdeveloper/11gdemos/ADF_Insider_Essentials/IterateRows/IterateRows.html
https://blogs.oracle.com/shay/entry/am_service_method_-_simple_dem

Comment: Thanks Shay. In theory that looks like the perfect solution to my problem. I'll give it a go. Thanks once again.